# How to check if all textview text is visible in scrollview

Tags: java, android, textview, scrollview

I tried checking if the height of the text in the `textview` is larger than the `scroll` view to handle situations where the user does not have to scroll to read the text but nothing online is working for me.

I tried solutions online but those don't work either

```
 if (binding.wvTermsAndCond.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {            
      // imageView is within the visible window
      Utils.showToast(mContext, "View is within the visible window", true);
 } else {
      // imageView is not within the visible window
      Utils.showToast(mContext, "View is not within the visible window", true);
 }
```

The not visible block was getting called

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a view is visible or not you can use these methods:

```
    public static boolean isVisible(final View view) {
    if (view == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!view.isShown()) {
      return false;
    }
    final Rect actualPosition = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(actualPosition);
    final Rect screen = new Rect(0, 0, getScreenWidth(), getScreenHeight());
    return actualPosition.intersect(screen);
  }

  public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
  }

  public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
  }
```